# Multiple connections to Google Cloud PSQL from Java App (SSL)

Tags: java, database, postgresql, ssl, google-cloud-platform

**Hello,**

I'm doing a project with the database, where the database is located on Google Cloud. The problem is with multiple connections, where the project should be able to access the database from multiple sources and the cloud enables this originally by manually whitelisting all the IPs, what is unacceptable for my scenario.

I've tried to use SSL, but unfortunately, I'm not able to connect no matter what I do. When I go without SSL, and I whitelist my IP, the connection is successful.

I'm kinda new to databases and on possible ways how to connect to them. Therefore, I need some basic explanation on what should I do or what am I doing wrong, since I'm getting kinda lost.

**Things I did following the tutorials from Postgre, Google, websites and already opened threads:**

1) Received 3 files from Cloud - *server-ca.pem, client-key.pem, client-cert.pem*, where I imported server-ca.pem and client-cert.pem into the Java Keystore

2) Tried both ways of naming the properties to connect to the database ( naming them all in URL and setting them as property) where the items are listed from PSQL generated by google cloud

**PSQL :**

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
hostaddr=MYIP \
port=5432 \
user=postgres dbname=postgres"
```

**The code:**
 (.pam files are included in the project directory)

```
public static Connection connectDb(){

    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://MYIP:5432/";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user","postgres");
    props.setProperty("password","admin");
    props.setProperty("ssl","true");
    props.setProperty("sslmode","verify-ca");
    props.setProperty("sslrootcert","server-ca.pem");
    props.setProperty("sslcert","client-cert.pem");
    props.setProperty("sslkey","client-key.pem");
    String name = "postgres";
    String password = "postgres";

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {

       classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}
```

**Error log:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
```

Any tips, help, tutorials, explanation on what should I do, what I did wrong, what kind of approach to choose will help a lot since I've tried all the things and possible ways to solve this problem I've found.

PS: Please, try to use basic and explanatory words and names for stuff, since I worry I might get lost and confused pretty easily. :)

**Thanks, Lukas.**

Comment: What does `telnet MYIP 5432` on the terminal give?

Comment: Nothing, just a blank terminal

Comment: That probably means postgres isn't properly exposed on your server.